# Date format in "a.m." in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

In an application I am getting an exception

> "NexusDB: : Query execution failed: 
>   Source string data is too wide (10) for the target field (8) [Field:
>   TIMESTART]  [$3CA0/15520]"

while trying to insert datestring `28/05/2018 9:10:00 a.m.` into a nexus db.

Am converting datetime to string and send it to dn as below

```
dte.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

But as am getting a.m. instead of AM this exception is thrown.

In which format of datetime I can get the date as  in a.m. format?

Comment: It sounds like you *want* "AM" rather than "a.m." - is that right? (And do you have to use that date/time format? If you could use ISO-8601 it would be a lot better in various ways...)

Comment: Note that "28/05/2018 9:10:00 AM" is still much longer than 8 characters, which is what the error message says is the maximum length of the field.

Comment: Storing in a standard would make life easier I'm sure. Your date should be as close to a date object, your UI or parsing routine should be in control of how the date is displayed. Storing as `2018-05-28T09:10` is much better and easier for your source code to understand.

Comment: @DaisyShipton he's only saving the "hh:mm tt" part though

Comment: @DaisyShipton: OP is using a `"hh:mm tt"` format string, which would be 8 characters wide.

Comment: @FishySwede: That's what the code looks like, but that's not what the exception suggests. It's all a bit confusing at the moment.

Comment: Additionally, if you're in full control of everything, an `HH:mm` format would be sortable, unlike `hh:mm tt`.

Comment: Agreed that it's confusing. I would guess that the issue is that "09:10 AM " is 8 characters, but OP is getting "09:10 a.m." which is 10 characters

Comment: @Sefe: Indeed, which is why I said "If". It was a suggestion for an improvement where possible, that's all.

Comment: There's always the incredibly ugly solution of doing dte.ToString("hh:mm tt").Replace(".", "").ToUpper();. I would avoid that kind of ugly code though

Answer (score 3):

When you are using this overload of the `ToString` method, you are using the current culture of the system. The AM/PM indicator depends on the culture, so if you want to use a predictable AM/PM indicator, you have to explicitly provide the conversion culture:

```
dte.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

For culture-independent storage, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is the recommended way to go. As it turns, out it also provides exactly the AM/PM designator you need.

Comment: It may be worth explicitly noting that `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator` *is* `"AM"` - it's not just predictable, but it's predictably the value that's wanted :)

Comment: In which culture we will get it as "a.m." or "A.M."?

Comment: When you explicitly specify the culture as in the answer, in none.